# Как написать этот код на питоне? Код у меня не работает. Какой из них я должен изменить?

Tags: python, pascal

```
// Pascal
var n:integer;
begin
  write('score = '); read(n);
  case n of
    1..59: writeln(2);
    60..69: writeln(3);
    70..89: writeln(4);
    90..100: writeln(5);
    else writeln('The score is in [0,100]');
  end;
end.

# Python
b = int(input('Score = '))
baholar = {
    range(0,60): '2',
    60<=b<70: '3',
    70<=b<90: '4',
    90<=b<=100: '5'
}
print(baholar.get(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [`match-case`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching):

```
b = int(input('Score = '))

match b:
    case num if 1 <= num <= 59:
        print('2')
    case num if 60 <= num <= 69:
        print('3')
    # и так далее
```

Можно использовать `if-elif`:

```
b = int(input('Score = '))

if 1 <= b <= 59:
    print('2')
elif 60 <= b <= 69:
    print('3')
# и так далее
```

Можно использовать словарь с `range`:

```
b = int(input('Score = '))

baholar = {
    b in range(1, 60): '2',
    b in range(60, 70): '3',
    # и так далее 
}

print(baholar.get(True))
```

Можно использовать словарь с неравенствами:

```
b = int(input('Score = '))

baholar = {
    1 <= b <= 59: '2',
    60 <= b <= 69: '3',
    # и так далее
}

print(baholar.get(True))
```

Comment: Только надо напомнить, что конструкция "match - case" введена  с версии 3.10.